# How to get only latest value by date from array of objects in Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I have array of objects with `username`, `userid` ,`date`, `amount`.
Now I want to get only each users recent transaction only.
How can I achieve that?

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "amount": 100,
        "date": "2021-12-02T05:24:24.215Z",
        "userid": "uid",
        "username": "username",
    },
    {
               "id": "2",
        "amount": 150,
        "date": "2021-12-02T05:24:24.215Z",
        "userid": "uid1",
        "username": "username1",
    },
    {
               "id": "3",
        "amount": 200,
        "date": "2021-11-02T05:24:24.215Z",
        "userid": "uid1",
        "username": "username1",
    }
]
```

In this case I want only array like below.
because `username1` has two transaction and I want to keep latest transaction only.
i.e. `2021-12-02T05:24:24.215Z`

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "amount": 100,
        "date": "2021-12-02T05:24:24.215Z",
        "userid": "uid",
        "username": "username",
    },
    {
               "id": "2",
        "amount": 150,
        "date": "2021-12-02T05:24:24.215Z",
        "userid": "uid1",
        "username": "username1",
    }
]
```

Comment: Read up on [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: You don't even need `Date` since ISO 8601 strings are designed to be lexically ordered. See [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Inspired by [eugenezinovyev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3271016/eugenezinovyev) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70551845/13658816), the below edit is added:

```
const getLastTxn = (txnList = []) => (
  Object.values(
    txnList.reduce(
      (f, i) => ({
        ...f,
        ...(!([i.username] in f) ||
          ([i.username] in f && i.date > f[i.username].date) ?
          {
            [i.username]: i
          } : {})
      }), {})
  )
);

console.log(getLastTxn(txnList));
```

**Explanation**

- Array.reduce initiates an empty object as 'f' (final-result).
- Then, for each iteration, 'i' (the iteration-object) is added to 'f'

  - if the username is not already present, OR
  - if the username exists and the 'date' in the 'i' (iteration) is greater than the date in the 'f' (final-result)
  - (In other words, skip transactions when date is lesser than what is already stored in 'f')
- The entire logic is wrapped into Object.values so, only the value-array of the 'f' object is returned.

Thank you [eugenezinovyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3271016/eugenezinovyev).

---

This requirement may be broken down into smaller pieces. First, find the list of transactions for each user & then, find the latest transaction. Finally, apply a filter to obtain only the transactions needed.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
const getLastTxn = (txnList = [], debug = true) => {
  const tMap = txnList.reduce((f, i) => ({
    ...f,
    ...(
      !([i.username] in f) ? {
        [i.username]: i.date
      } : {
        [i.username]: i.date > f[i.username] ? i.date : f[i.username]
      }
    )
  }), {});
  debug && console.log('map: ', tMap);
  return txnList.filter(t => tMap[t.username] === t.date);
};

getLastTxn(txnList);
```

**Approach**:

- Use Array.reduce to convert the array into an object
- The key will be username
- The value will be the date of the 'latest transaction'
- Once we have a map (username: latest-txn-date), just need to filter the array.

And, here is code-snippet to demo-quickly.

```js
const txnList = [{
    "id": "1",
    "amount": 100,
    "date": "2021-12-02T05:24:24.215Z",
    "userid": "uid",
    "username": "username",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "amount": 150,
    "date": "2021-12-02T05:24:24.215Z",
    "userid": "uid1",
    "username": "username1",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "amount": 200,
    "date": "2021-11-02T05:24:24.215Z",
    "userid": "uid1",
    "username": "username1",
  }
];

const getLastTxn = (txnList = [], debug = true) => {
  const tMap = txnList.reduce((f, i) => ({
    ...f,
    ...(!([i.username] in f) ? {
      [i.username]: i.date
    } : {
      [i.username]: i.date > f[i.username] ? i.date : f[i.username]
    })
  }), {});
  debug && console.log('map: ', tMap);
  if (debug) {
    const result = txnList.filter(t => tMap[t.username] === t.date);
    console.log('result: ', result);
    return result;
  } else return txnList.filter(t => tMap[t.username] === t.date);
};

getLastTxn(txnList);
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version of the jsN00b's answer. The point here is not to re-create aggregate object in reduce function to avoid redundant memory allocations and simplify code by using Object.values function.

```js
const transactions = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "amount": 100,
        "date": "2021-12-04T05:24:24.215Z",
        "userid": "uid",
        "username": "username",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "amount": 150,
        "date": "2021-12-02T05:24:24.215Z",
        "userid": "uid1",
        "username": "username1",
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "amount": 200,
        "date": "2021-11-02T05:24:24.215Z",
        "userid": "uid1",
        "username": "username1",
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "amount": 120,
        "date": "2021-12-03T05:24:24.215Z",
        "userid": "uid",
        "username": "username",
    },
];

const getLatestUserTransactions = (userTransactions) => {
    const groupedByUser = userTransactions.reduce((aggregate, transaction) => {
        if (!(transaction.username in aggregate)) {
            aggregate[transaction.username] = transaction;
        } else {
            aggregate[transaction.username] = transaction.date > aggregate[transaction.username].date
                ? transaction
                : aggregate[transaction.username]
        }

        return aggregate;
    }, {});

    return Object.values(groupedByUser);
};

console.log(getLatestUserTransactions(transactions));
```